# MVVM light sending message from ViewModel to View

Tags: c#, mvvm, messenger

I'm very new to MVVM light and im having some problems using the Messenger..

Im trying to send a message from the ViewModel to the View but this is not working for me, I have tried going through posts and sample code but i think there is something very simple that i am missing.. i appreciate your help..

In my ViewModel I send a message

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new ClearNewProjectSettingsMessage());
```

This is my Message class, I dont really know what to put here because everything is in my View class

```
public class ClearNewProjectSettingsMessage
{
    public ClearNewProjectSettingsMessage()
    {

    }
}
```

I register the message in the Views constructor:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<ClearNewProjectSettingsMessage>(
            this,
            () => ClearSettings()
);
```

This unfortunately does not compile so I tried this:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<ClearNewProjectSettingsMessage>(this,ClearSettings);
```

But it still does not work..

This is the method i want to call (in the view):

```
private void ClearSettings()
{
        passwordBox.Clear();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I have not ever used MVVM Light Messenger, but as with any event aggregator/message bus, it makes sense so that the handler method takes in the object *that it handles* as an argument:

I have checked the source code and the registration looks as follows:

```
public virtual void Register<TMessage>(object recipient, Action<TMessage> action)
```

With that in mind, this definition:

```
private void HandleClearSettings(ClearNewProjectSettingsMessage message)
{
}
```

should fix your registration:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<ClearNewProjectSettingsMessage>(this, HandleClearSettings);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I didnt realise that the handler method takes in the object it handles as an argument.. I registered the message using this: Messenger.Default.Send(new ClearNewQCProjectSettingsMessage()); is that ok? I dont really understand how you are registering your message because you dont have anything that points to 'ClearNewProjectSettingsMessage', i need to look into that further, could you point me to any resources? thanks!

Comment: @Manal [Here's an article I found on Google](http://tonychampion.net/blog/index.php/2010/07/messaging-in-silverlight-with-mvvm-light/), and [here is the source code](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest) that you can check whenever you are in doubt. :)